# Using variable names from data frame in operation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data which looks like this:

```
dfA <- data.frame("First Var Name" = rnorm(20,3),
                  "Second Var Name" = rnorm(20,5), 
                  "Third Var Name" = rnorm(20,4),
                  "Fourth Var Name" = rnorm(20,4))

dfB <- data.frame(Grouping = c("A","B","B","A"), 
                  Varname = c("First Var Name", "Second Var Name", "Third Var Name", "Fourth Var Name"))
```

I would like to use dfB in dplyr to `group_by` Grouping, take the first principal component of the variables in that group applied to `dfA`. I have tried something like

```
dfC <- dfB %>%
    group_by(Grouping) %>%
    relevantvars <- .$Varname %>%
    data.frame(`Grouping' = prcomp(dfA[,relevantvars])$x[,1])
```

However, grabbing the variable names and using the grouping as a variable names has proven tricky. I have also tried in combination with the paste command, but that did not work either. Here is what I am hoping to get:

```
dfC <- data.frame(A = prcomp(dfA[,c(1,4)])$x[,1], B = prcomp(dfA[,c(2,3)])$x[,1])
```

Comment: If you have variable names stored as character values, you need to use dplyr's standard evaluation variants, e.g. `group_by_`. See [the NSE vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html).

Comment: Also, naming columns things with spaces makes dplyr's NSE somewhat pointless by requiring a huge amount of backticks.

Comment: That is how the data came in R, I can change this before using dplyr, but I was trying to mimic the original data as best as possible. I'll look at NSE, thanks.

Comment: @alistaire I'm not seeing how SE allows me to use the value of Grouping and get the variable names stored as character values. Could you push me a bit further in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You actually *don't* want to group by those variables; you want to group their values by their names. That's more easily accomplished if you reshape `dfA` to long form, and then nest the requisite data for each PCA as a list column of data.frames, which you can use `purrr::map` to iterate over (or just `lapply`, if you prefer). You'll need to reshape to wide for `prcomp`, which in this case is simpler with `unstack` than `tidyr::spread`, which is finicky about indices.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(47)    # make generated data reproducible

dfA <- data.frame(`First Var Name` = rnorm(20, 3), 
                  `Second Var Name` = rnorm(20, 5), 
                  `Third Var Name` = rnorm(20, 4), 
                  `Fourth Var Name` = rnorm(20, 4))

dfB <- data.frame(Grouping = c("A", "B", "B", "A"), 
                  Varname = c("First Var Name", "Second Var Name", "Third Var Name", "Fourth Var Name"))

# unless you tell it not to, `data.frame` will replace spaces with periods, so update Varname
dfB <- dfB %>% mutate(Varname = make.names(Varname))

dfC <- dfA %>% gather() %>% 
    left_join(dfB, by = c("key" = "Varname")) %>% 
    nest(-Grouping) %>% 
    mutate(pca = map(data, ~prcomp(unstack(.x, value ~ key))$x[, 1])) %>% 
    unnest(pca) %>% 
    unstack(pca ~ Grouping)

dfC
#>              A           B
#> 1  -1.74340058 -0.80430828
#> 2  -0.90015763  0.55121748
#> 3   0.72162180  0.18540745
#> 4   0.68609468 -0.11332615
#> 5  -0.68003234  0.43964407
#> 6   1.39659346  0.37532545
#> 7   1.08617617 -1.44789829
#> 8   0.61576966 -1.01015131
#> 9  -1.09667280 -1.78978142
#> 10  1.14931837 -0.16714979
#> 11  1.02694416 -0.08245775
#> 12  0.03852488 -0.83134735
#> 13  0.05820030 -1.97289196
#> 14  2.35215929  1.62823022
#> 15 -0.38723810  2.24902954
#> 16 -1.65000542 -0.43809477
#> 17  0.19792790  0.47133845
#> 18 -0.89921705  0.85804619
#> 19 -0.88727866  1.01371806
#> 20 -1.08532810  0.88545017
```